# Django Site Can't Find Admin Styling or Media Files when Debug = False

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm having trouble getting my django site running with debug = False.

**Info:**

- Currently, Debug = False
- I am running on my local host
- I'm using Wagtail. But from what I've read, the problems I'm dealing with are more Django-related.

**Problem:**

- When I go to the site on my local host, it can find static files, but it can't get any 'media' files.Example: `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/block-alphabet-abc.width-400.png Internal Server Error`
- When I log into the admin panel, the look and feel is off in some places (like css components may be missing).
- When I go to edit a page, the look and feel is still off and the web developer tool has a bunch of 500 errors saying things like the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/wagtailadmin/js/date-time-chooser.js?v=3a1ab45f` is missing.

**What I have tried:**

- I have ran `python manage.py collectstatic`. Doing that does not create the media directory though. It adds the wagtail admin files, but none of them have the little hash at the end.
- I tried running python manage.py compress, but I keep getting the error that none of the templates have the compression tag (which is true).
- I added logging, but I'm not sure how to resolve the errors.

**Question:**
How do I create the media directory? How do I get the wagtail admin files added in the right format so they can be found?

**STATIC & MEDIA URLs in settings.py**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
]

# ManifestStaticFilesStorage is recommended in production, to prevent outdated
# Javascript / CSS assets being served from cache (e.g. after a Wagtail upgrade).
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/html/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = "/var/www/html/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**Top of the Base.html Template that use STATIC_URL:**

```
{% load static wagtailuserbar %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags site_tags %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">


        <title>
            {% block title %}
            {% if self.seo_title %}{{ self.seo_title }}{% else %}{{ self.title }}{% endif %}
            {% endblock %}
            {% block title_suffix %}
            {% with self.get_site.site_name as site_name %}
            {% if site_name %} | {{ site_name }}{% endif %}
            {% endwith %}
            {% endblock %}
        </title>


        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/bootstrap-3.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/bootstrap-3.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/bootstrap-3.4.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    {% get_global_settings request=request as global_settings %}
    {% if global_settings.site_logo %} 
        {% image global_settings.site_logo width-2000 as site_logo %}
        <link rel="icon" href="{{ site_logo.url }}" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
    {% endif %}

        {# Global stylesheets #}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/sitename.css' %}">

        {% block extra_css %}
        {# Override this in templates to add extra stylesheets #}
        {% endblock %}

    </head>
```

**Logs:**
These logs show what happens when I go to edit a page in the admin panel.

```
Exception while resolving variable 'field_classes' in template 'wagtailadmin/edit_handlers/single_field_panel.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<local-directory-to-app>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
  File "/<local-directory-to-app>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'field_classes'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<local-directory-to-app>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 835, in _resolve_lookup
    if isinstance(current, BaseContext) and getattr(type(current), bit):
AttributeError: type object 'Context' has no attribute 'field_classes'
```

These logs show what happens when I go to a front-end site page.

```
Exception while resolving variable 'STATIC_URL' in template 'home/home_page.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<local-directory-to-app>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
  File "/<local-directory-to-app>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'STATIC_URL'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<local-directory-to-app>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 835, in _resolve_lookup
    if isinstance(current, BaseContext) and getattr(type(current), bit):
AttributeError: type object 'RequestContext' has no attribute 'STATIC_URL'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<local-directory-to-app>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'STATIC_URL'

...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<local-directory-to-app>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [STATIC_URL] in [{'True': True, 'None': None, 'False': False}, {'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'ERROR': 40, 'INFO': 20, 'SUCCESS': 25, 'WARNING': 30}, 'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: <function csrf.<locals>._get_val at 0x7efe01e64598>>, 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/media/images/twitter-logo.width-40.png'>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <function AuthenticationMiddleware.process_request.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7efe01e64400>>, 'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x7efe01e65128>, 'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x7efe01e509e8>}, {}, {'request_path': '/media/images/twitter-logo.width-40.png', 'exception': '"/var/www/html/media/images/twitter-logo.width-40.png" does not exist'}]
Exception while resolving variable 'page' in template '404.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<local-directory-to-app>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/<local-directory-to-app>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/<local-directory-to-app>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/<local-directory-to-app>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 42, in serve
    raise Http404(_('"%(path)s" does not exist') % {'path': fullpath})
django.http.response.Http404: "/var/www/html/media/images/walking-in-tunnel.width-2000.png" does not exist
```

Comment: What are your values for STATIC_URL, STATICFILES_DIRS, STATIC_ROOT, MEDIA_URL, and MEDIA_ROOT? It may also be helpful to see the view and template that are being used.

Comment: @schillingt Okay. I added the base.html that all my other templates inherit. I also added the url configs from settings.py.

Answer (score 1):

Django's runserver is not to be used in production.  By setting `DEBUG` to `True`, you are now running in a production-like environment.  runserver [won't serve media files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#serving-static-files-with-the-development-server), so if you want to mimic a server-style setup on a dev machine, what you should do is install a production-type server such as Apache and set it up to serve media files as you normally would with the proper alias.  You would also need to create an alias for static files.

Comment: Okay so, I did collectstatic to /var/www/html on my machine. So when I go to localhost, I see the static files. And at the bottom of the localhost page, it says "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80". When I run "runserver", it runs on http:// 127.0.0.1 : 8000 / from my local directory. So to launch a django site, is the proper way to copy my entire django app to that /var/www/html directory?

Comment: No.  Follow these directions (and don't even start runserver if you want to test in a production-like setting):  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/